# How to create a mulit-page-application (with Vue or React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application, multi-page-application

I'm a bit confused with single-page-applications and multi-page-applications. I already know the difference between both but I struggle a bit with creating a MPA... So far I only build some apps  with React and Vue but they where all SPA (so they where client side rendered). I don't understand how I can build a multi-page-app with React or Vue that renders server side so that when I go to a different path (from /home to /contact for example) the page is rendered new?
Can someone help me or give me a link to a tutorial or something else because all tutorials or courses I've watched only focused on SPA.

Comment: Have you looked through various forums such as: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/best-way-to-create-a-mpa-with-vue-js/60723? Or looked at other posts on stack? Such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240582/vue-js-best-way-to-implement-mpamulti-page-app-in-laravel?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Looks like you are confused with `SPA` and `MPA` ? It's not about client side and server side rendered. The major difference is, In SPA entry point is single but in MPA every page is a standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a router to your Vue or React app for multi-page stuff. There are also many good routers available for both frameworks in the npm registry.

Or you can use a third-party framework ([Next.js](https://nextjs.org) for React, [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) for Vue)

Answer (score 0):

[Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) could be a good starting point for React. Its a framework on top of React and encourages SSR.